# Getting resource issue duplication related issue?

Tags: android, android-resources

The error message is the following: `android 'attr/value' with config ''`

Here is the version setup:

```
compileSdkVersion = 27
buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 21
targetSdkVersion = 27`
```

The error message specifies the name of [loading-dots](https://github.com/EyalBira/loading-dots/tree/master/loading-dots/src/main) library, which has really less resources which doesn't interfere with the other resources.

The question is now how to parse this error message properly to a normal human understandable language to be able to find where the issue comes from.

What does mean?

```
 - "attr/value"
 - "with config ''"
```

Here is the complete log message

```
:app:generateDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: duplicate value for resource \u0027attr/value\u0027 with config \u0027\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/karate/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/loading-dots-1.0.2.aar/53c3c73936c7c0b67d125304a8d501c0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":3,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":619,"endColumn":60,"endOffset":675}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource previously defined here.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/karate/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/loading-dots-1.0.2.aar/53c3c73936c7c0b67d125304a8d501c0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":3,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":619,"endColumn":60,"endOffset":675}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}


Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

Comment: Can you post your entire log, not just a part of it

Comment: @NizaSiwale I updated the question with the log message.

Answer (score 0):

The library has an issue, it clashes with a system xml attribute. That's why you are getting the error. Moreover, the repo you've linked to is backwards as it doesn't have a `values.xml` try to change the compile version to a lower figure. Maybe

```
compile 'com.eyalbira.loadingdots:loading-dots:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue happens with this version as well.

Comment: Then clown the library and rename the xml atrributes